# How can I sync original photos from iCloud to a non-Apple computer?

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

How can I automatically copy original-quality (e.g. HEIC) photos from iCloud to a non-Apple computer? I have two decades of photos from various cameras I’ve owned over the years organized on my computer and am trying to understand how to reliably add my Apple-held photos to it.

- I’ve seen that I can download photos manually by using “Download: Unmodified Original” in the iCloud web interface, but this is tedious.
- I tried using the iCloud app for Windows, but that apparently only exposes reduced-quality JPEG exports. My iPhone has a setting for “Transfer to Mac or PC: Keep Originals” but I don’t see an analogous setting in the iCloud app.

I’m ready to do substantial initial work to set this up (e.g. custom scripting, running a VM, etc.) but at this point I’m not sure what to even try next.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of doing this I suggest the simplest one .

First you need to download iMazing app on your windows .

[Download iMazing for PC](https://imazing.com/download/windows)

[Download iMazing for MacOS](https://imazing.com/download/macos)

Launch iMazing and connect your device to your Mac or PC.
Select your device in the sidebar, then select "Photos".
Click "Import from Folder", and select the music you want to import.
Transfer your Photos.